# I need to print all words that start with the letter "*" in to another output txt (13000 lines) but this program works with like 200 or so

Tags: java

```
private static void readFile1(String in, String out) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(in));

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    BufferedWriter writer = null;

    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
          new FileOutputStream(out), "utf-8"));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.length() > 0)
        {
            String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
            for(String word : words)
            {
                if(word.charAt(0)=='*')
                {
                    //System.out.println(word);
                    writer.write(word);
                    writer.newLine();
                }
            }
        }          
    }

    br.close();
    writer.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

}

Can someone help me with this one? 
In cmd i get something like "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:String index out of range:0

Comment: Could you be more specific?
I don`t master java and i know thiss is a stupid question for most of you

Comment: Debug `word` and look at the value before you look for a character. See what the value is right before the Exception is thrown

Comment: You're probably reading a blank line.  Add trim() to the line length greater than zero test.

Comment: @Gilbert Not going to fix the problem completely from what I remember about the intricacies of `split()`.

Comment: Can someone be more specific? I mean i am a beginner in java and when i say beginner i say i have no clue can u say something like "Delete that and put that instead" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place you seem to be referencing an index on a string is this `if-statement`:

```
if(word.charAt(0)=='*')
```

Change your if statement to be:

```
if(!word.isEmpty() && word.charAt(0)=='*')
```

This will first check if the `word` is empty and if it is not, then it will look for the proper `char`

**UPDATE**

You should add in a NULL check on `word` as well, just to avoid a `NullPointerException`

```
if(word != null && !word.isEmpty() && word.charAt(0)=='*')
```

Comment: if downvoting, provide why because it obviously worked